# The best way to search according to distance in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, geospatial

In ror, suppose I have a list of geo referenced data in my database
(each record have latitude and longitude column) what is the best way to implement search according-to-distance function?

I am aware of geokit for ruby. But I am looking for other suggestions.
If it is platform dependent, I plan to use heroku as deployment platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you  checked [rubygeocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) ,

read this about the [distance queries](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries)

Following is a [great screencast by ryan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)

Comment: Great links! I think it would help future readers of this question if you could give a little more context for each one, in line with StackOverflow answer guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the gem Geocoder.

As specified in [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder/1.1.6/frames) -

> Geocoder is a complete geocoding solution for Ruby. With Rails it adds
>   geocoding (by street or IP address), reverse geocoding (find street
>   address based on given coordinates), and distance queries. It's as
>   simple as calling geocode on your objects, and then using a scope like
>   Venue.near("Billings, MT").

With geocoded objects you can do things like this:

```
if obj.geocoded?
  obj.nearbys(30)                      # other objects within 30 miles
  obj.distance_from([40.714,-100.234]) # distance from arbitrary point to object
  obj.bearing_to("Paris, France")      # direction from object to arbitrary point
end
```